# Как образовывать прилагательные с суффиксами -н- и -ов-?

Tags: прилагательные, морфология, словообразование

Как можно объяснить иностранному студенту, для каких прилагательных надо использовать суффикс -ов-/-ев-, а в каких случаях суффикс -н-?

Например, есть прилагательные "яблочный", "молочный" и "тучный", но нет прилагательных "яблоковый", "молоковый" и "туковый". С другой стороны, есть прилагательные "сливовый", и никто не говорит "сливный (сок)".

Я думала, что это как-то связано с конечной согласной корня, например, прилагательные, образованный от слов на -к-, образуются с суффиксом -н-. Но такие слова как "замковый" и "замочный", "паровой" и "парный" не согласуются с этим правилом. Может, есть целая система правил?

Answer (score 2):

Извините, но прилагательное [*туковый*](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/256408/%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9) существует, также существует и [*сливный*](http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?stype=undefined&SWord=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) (сок), хотя оно отмечено в словарях как устаревшее.

От одного и того же корня часто образуются оба прилагательные, и с `-ов-/-ев-`, и с `-н-`, оба слова в таких парах, как правило, выступают с разными значениями или с разными оттенками значения. Примеров предостаточно:

> стенный - стенной - стеновой
>
> [на]польный - половой
>
> стольный - столовый - столовой
>
> кружный - кружной - круговой
>
> плужный - плуговой
>
> сердечный - сердцевой
>
> [на]домный - домовый - домовой
>
> конный - коневой
>
> передний - передовой
>
> ладный - ладовый
>
> снежный - снеговой

И так далее, и тому подобное. Боюсь, что единого правила тут не существует. Единственное что можно заметить в таких парах, это то, что слова с `-н-` имеют более конкретный, материальный смысл, в то время как слова с `-ов-/-ев-` - более абстрактный, отвлечённый. Но даже это выполняется далеко не всегда.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что здесь играет роль традиция словоупотребления, а также тот факт, что из пары возможных слов с разными суффиксами одно имеет неудачное или неуместное созвучие с другим существующим прилагательным.

Например "замковый" - относящийся к зАмку (строению), а "замочный" - относящийся к замкУ (запорному механизму).

Молоковый может быть от слова "молоки" (рыбные внутренности).

"Сливный" скорее происходит от слова "слив", т.е. синоним слова "сточный". (Кстати, в свое время был удивлен выражением "помидоровый сок", оказывается так тоже говорят, хотя я бы употребил "помидорный").

Кроме того некоторые слова из пары могут иметь "плохую славу". Так например из пары слов волнующий/волнительный второе считается "плохим" и уже мало кто помнит почему. Оказывается в конце XIX - начале ХХ века "волнительный" начал использовать Станиславский  для обозначения особого оттенка волнения. Оно проникло в актерский жаргон и со временем приобрело оттенок жеманства. Происхождение слова забылось, а плохое отношение к нему осталось до сих пор (хотя когда-то его употреблял Толстой). В то же время из пары трогающий/трогательный сегодня используется второе, а "трогающий" уже практически не используется (об этом [рассказывает Ирина Левонтина](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7wdgtPB8Tk&noredirect=1#t=920)).

Comment: Как мне кажется, вопрос был об образовании прилагательных от одного и того же корня, вы же говорите о разных корнях: _замóк_ - это от "замыкать", а _зáмок_ - заимствование из польского, _тучный_ и _туковый_ - от слова "тук" (жир), а _туча_ - это совершенно другой корень, с жиром не связанный, _слива_ (плод) и _слив_ (от "сливать") тоже имеют совершенно разные корни.

Comment: @YellowSky Я имею в виду что из двух возможных вариантов один может быть "уникальным" для корня, а второй иметь неудачное или неуместное созвучие со словом образованным от другого корня. В результате один вариант более предпочтительный.